# Makefile script does not run properly

Tags: makefile

I have these files `main.c`, `fun.c`, and `fun.h`. I want to use `makefile` script to run instead of traditional compiling approach. The one who posted the following makefile script said this script will automatically capture the file names in the same directory, so all I need is to navigate to the project directory and write in the terminal `$ make`. I created a file `makefile` and put the following script:

```
TARGET = prog
LIBS = -lm
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

However, I get this error:
`make: *** No rule to make target`default'.  Stop.`

I tried `$make -v` and got:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

I think I misunderstood him! Kindly, what is missing here? Thank you

Comment: Makefiles are **not** scripts ... and I'd consider using them **very** traditional (but your approach to just compile anything named `*.c`  definitely isn't very traditional ...)

Comment: Your `default` target btw serves no purpose at all in this Makefile. Why not just write `all: $(TARGET)` as the first rule?

Comment: It seems correct to me, just remember, in Makefile, those blank spaces (4 blank in sequence) must be tabbed ('\t').

Comment: @Amadeus Do I have to compile each `*.c` first? I thought makefile takes care of that.

Comment: I've just attempted to reproduce your problem, but it worked fine for me...
What does `make -v` say for you?

Comment: @PeterSW I update my post. BTW, I am running my code on Mac OSX

Comment: @Alonso Just make. It has to take care of that too

Comment: Sounds to me like you are running `make` in a different directory to your makefile.

Comment: @user657267 No it is the same directory. BTW, my makefile is named as `makefile.make` is that correct?

Comment: You need to rename it to Makefile, or makefile

Comment: Nope, by default `make` will only look for `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile` in that order. Change it or use `make -f makefile.make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing separator error is because you're not using tabs for the "recipe".

For instance, your TARGET target has a prerequisite of $(OBJECTS), once Make knows that is there (or Makes it) then it will continue to the recipe.

```
    $(TARGET): $(PREREQUISITES)
    ->(TAB) $(RECIPE)
```

Comment: Correct. I just spotted that as well. Thank you

Comment: No problem, I would've just commented but have no rep! Have fun!